# Residue of $f(z) = e^z \csc^2 z $

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

i know the singularities exist at $z=k\pi$ with pole of order 2.

I've tried to do this

$$
e^z = 1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\cdots \\
\sin^2z = z^2 -\frac{z^4}{3}+\frac{7z^6}{20}+ \cdots
$$

By long division, I would get

$$
e^z \csc^2 z = \frac{1}{z^2} + \frac{1}{z}+\cdots
$$

Hence, Res($e^z \csc^2 z ,k\pi$)$ = 1$?

However, [Wolfram Answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=res+(e%5Ezcsc%5E2z)) doesn't corresponds to my answer. Where did I made a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z=a$ be a pole of order $2$ of $f(z)$ then you must to find the limit
$$\lim_{z\to a}\left((z-a)^2f(z)\right)'$$
for residue there. So with $z-k\pi=w$ then
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Res}_{z=k\pi}\dfrac{e^z}{\sin^2z}
&= \lim_{z\to k\pi}\Big[(z-k\pi)^2\dfrac{e^z}{\sin^2z}\Big]'\\
&= \lim_{w\to0}\Big[w^2\dfrac{e^we^{k\pi}}{\sin^2w}\Big]'\\
&= e^{k\pi}\lim_{w\to0}\Big[e^w\left(\dfrac{w}{\sin w}\right)^2\Big]'\\
&= e^{k\pi}\times1\\
&= e^{k\pi}
\end{align}

Comment: one thing i don't get is why can we evaluate the limit of $e^w \left(\frac{w}{\sin w}\right)^2$ first . Aren't we supposed to differentiate first then evaluate the limit?

Comment: Of course. First differentiate then evaluate the limit as my note says!